# Highlight the entire line if a particular string found using python regex

Tags: python

The below is my input string.

```
This is my world. \nI don't like food. \nMy world is my mom.
```

If i found a string 'world' in the input string then the entire line should be highlighted when i'm printing it.

expected output.

**This is my world.**
I don't like food.
**My world is my mom.**

Comment: How do you **highlight** the line? using double "*" or what?

Comment: it will good if that row alone prints in different color

Comment: Yeah how do I highlight it?

Comment: from colorama import init, Fore

re.sub(r'\\n.+(world).+\\n', Fore.BLUE + r'\1' +'This is my world')

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
from colorama import Fore

my_word = 'world'
my_string = "This is my world. \nI don't like food. \nMy world is my mom."
# this will split the string on new lines
lines = my_string.split('\n')

for line in lines:
    if my_word in line.lower():
        print(f'{Fore.BLUE}{line}')
    else:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix/lunix terminals then add code `'\033[1m'` before the line and `'\033[0m'` after the line to represent it in bold characters.you can use function something like

```
sent = input("Enter the sentences here")
start = "\033[1m"
end = "\033[0m"
print(" ".join([start + i + end for i in sents.split("/n") if i.find("world")!=1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sentence based on newline or fullstop. Then you can enclose it between `"\033[1m"` and `"\033[0m"` to make it **bold** based on an if/else condition in a list comprehension.

```
search_word="world"
txt="This is my world. \nI don't like food. \nMy world is my mom."
txt.split('.')
print(".".join([("\033[1m"+t+"\033[0m") if search_word in t else t for t in txt.split('.')]))
```